# How to check for no valid numbers in WPF with DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-annotations

I'm working on a WPF application with MVVM pattern in which i use DataAnnotations for validation.
So i implemented a solution like that in this [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22660.data-validation-in-mvvm.aspx).

Then i tried to add a property to my viewmodel - called "Age" - which shall only accept numbers and have a range between 1 and 100.

```
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{1,3}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid number")]
    [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Age should be between 1 to 100")]
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the age.
    /// </summary>
    public int Age
    {
        get { return GetValue(() => Age); }
        set { SetValue(() => Age, value); }
    }
```

And on my WPF window i got a textbox which is bound to Age:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="tbx_age"
             ToolTip="The age"
             Text="{Binding Age, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
    </TextBox>
```

As i'm starting the application the textbox is preallocated with zero ("0").
When i replace the zero in the textbox by "1a" i get the error message "The value '1a' cannot be converted".
This is no regular message from my code and i can't explain where it's coming from.
Have i made a mistake in the regular expression or something else?

I have uploaded my testproject to GitHub:
[Repository](https://github.com/patrickpirzer/WpfValidation)
The project which i mean is named "Validation_DataAnnotations".

Thanks in advance!

This is the class PropertyChangedNotification which i use for notification and validation:

```
public abstract class PropertyChangedNotification : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    #endregion

    #region Protected

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value of a property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertySelector">Expression tree contains the property definition.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The property value.</param>
    protected void SetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector, T value)
    {
        string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);

        SetValue<T>(propertyName, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value of a property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The property value.</param>
    protected void SetValue<T>(string propertyName, T value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
        }

        _values[propertyName] = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of a property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertySelector">Expression tree contains the property definition.</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the property or default value if not exist.</returns>
    protected T GetValue<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector)
    {
        string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);

        return GetValue<T>(propertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of a property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property value.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property.</param>
    /// <returns>The value of the property or default value if not exist.</returns>
    protected T GetValue<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
        }

        object value;
        if (!_values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out value))
        {
            value = default(T);
            _values.Add(propertyName, value);
        }

        return (T)value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates current instance properties using Data Annotations.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">This instance property to validate.</param>
    /// <returns>Relevant error string on validation failure or <see cref="System.String.Empty"/> on validation success.</returns>
    protected virtual string OnValidate(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
        }

        string error = string.Empty;
        var value = GetValue(propertyName);
        var results = new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>(1);
        var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
            value,
            new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
            {
                MemberName = propertyName
            },
            results);

        if (!result)
        {
            var validationResult = results.First();
            error = validationResult.ErrorMessage;
        }

        return error;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Change Notification

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    #region Data Validation

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("IDataErrorInfo.Error is not supported, use IDataErrorInfo.this[propertyName] instead.");
        }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return OnValidate(propertyName);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Privates

    private string GetPropertyName(LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }

    private object GetValue(string propertyName)
    {
        object value;
        if (!_values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out value))
        {
            var propertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType()).Find(propertyName, false);
            if (propertyDescriptor == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
            }

            value = propertyDescriptor.GetValue(this);
            _values.Add(propertyName, value);
        }

        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Debugging

    /// <summary>
    /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
    /// a public property with the specified name. This
    /// method does not exist in a Release build.
    /// </summary>
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        // Verify that the property name matches a real, 
        // public, instance property on this object.
        if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
        {
            string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

            if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                throw new Exception(msg);
            else
                Debug.Fail(msg);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns whether an exception is thrown, or if a Debug.Fail() is used
    /// when an invalid property name is passed to the VerifyPropertyName method.
    /// The default value is false, but subclasses used by unit tests might
    /// override this property's getter to return true.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

    #endregion // Debugging Aides
}
```

Comment: Does this error occur as exception or as message on your textbox?

Comment: It occurs as tooltip of the textbox element. In the XAML i have defined a style for displaying validation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an `int` property can *never* be set to anything else than an `int` value so your property setter will never be invoked if you set the Text property of the TextBox to "1a". No regular expression or data annotation in the world will solve this.

What you can do to customize the error message that appears when the WPF runtime tries to convert the value "1a" to an `int` before the property is set is to use a `ValidationRule`:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Age" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:StringToIntValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
    ...
</TextBox>
```

---

```
public class StringToIntValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out i))
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a valid integer value.");
    }
}
```

There is a full example and more information about this available in the following blog post: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/

Note that it is not the responsibility of the view model to verify that its Age property is set to an `int` value. This is the responsibility of the control or the view.

Comment: Hello mm8. Thank You very much for Your solution. As You can see in my GitHub-repository, i had the same code in the project "Validation_ValidationRule".

Answer (score 1):

You are binding your TextBox.TextProperty against the int-Property 'Age', thus WPF will already need to convert the string to an integer, in order to assign the value to your property.

If you want to do all the conversion yourself, you can bind to a string-Property instead.
Alternatively, you could just set ValidatesOnDataErrors=False in your binding, then non-numeric values will be silently ignored, numeric values will change the bound property.